# autorelease, release object when function is finished

Tags: iphone, memory-management

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{ 
   static NSCharacterSet *charSet = nil;
    if (!charSet) {
        charSet = [[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet] retain];
    }
    NSRange loc = [(NSString*)textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
    if (loc.location != NSNotFound) {
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"error!",@"")
                                                             message:@"description."
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"")
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
        [errorAlert release];
        return NO;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

I have a question connected with autorelease.

I know that when I create object in that way:

```
 charset =[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
```

object is autoreleased.

And I have question - reason for why there is a *retain*, on this object, is that - object is released after first call function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because charSet is declared as static. Normal scoping rules apply, so it's only visible within this method. But, static variables *don't* live on the stack, and keep their values when the method returns, so they still have the same value if it's called again. That's why there's the "if (!charSet)" - this checks to see if the object has been created yet, so the existing object can be re-used if so.

Without the -retain, the NSCharacterSet object is autoreleased, and the block of memory where it lived can (and will) be used for something else. But the `charSet*` pointer to that memory is not reset to nil when that happens. It still has the old value; since that value is non-nil, the `if(!charSet)` is false, so a new object won't be created. But, since the old object was destroyed, there's no telling what might be at the memory to which that pointer refers - it could be random garbage, it could be some other object, it could be anything.

Comment: ok, greeat I understand, static causes that variable doesn't change his value when function is finished. But could you explain again why when I don't add retain, it doesn't work?

Comment: OK, I expanded the second part of the answer - did that help?

Comment: it seems that charSet is released  when function is finished and as u said in charSet is random garbage. I think I understand, am I?

Comment: Minor nitpick - charSet is released whenever the autorelease pool is drained. That happens at the end of every trip through the event-processing loop, which is not necessarily at the end of this method call. For instance, if something is using Cocoa Bindings to observe changes to textField, the relevant notification methods will also be called as part of processing this event.

Comment: hmm, but u said _since the old object was destroyed_.

Comment: Yes, the old object was destroyed at the end of the previous focus changing event, during which this method was previously called. When this method is called again, it will be as part of *another* event. Each event has just one autorelease pool, regardless of whether handling that event involves one method call or a hundred. That pool gets drained at the end of the event, not at the end of each method call.

Comment: ok I understand old object was destroyed at the end of the event. [link](http://parmanoir.com/When_does_autorelease_release_%3F) event starts when you for example clicked mouse, and it calls method _mouseDown:_, the cycle end when your return from _mouseDown:_ method. Could you show me an example when event lifetime is longer then method?

Comment: Your own example - a button's mouseDown: method will call the action method on its target. That action method might show or hide a window, for example, which results in the window calling the appropriate delegate methods. All of that occurs within the lifetime of a single iteration of the event loop.

Comment: ok, know I understand, thanks for patient. You really helped me.

Comment: But, there is one more thing.. ;D If i call retain i have to release this object. So I should declare charSet as ivar, and release it in dealloc?

Comment: If this controller will last the lifetime of your app, it won't really matter, since you won't hit -dealloc until your whole app is being shut down anyway. By the time you get to that point, managing memory for individual objects is like rearranging deck chairs while the titanic sinks underneath them. But making it an ivar might keep the Leaks tool from reporting it as a leak.